# Expected winnings for playing a game where you win twice as much as losses

Tags: probability

Suppose you play a game in a casino with a 50% chance of winning and you win twice as much as you bet. The casino doesn't limit your bets, so your strategy is to go double-or-nothing on your losses. For example, if you bet $4 and lose, you would then bet $8. So if you won that second time, you'd still net profit $4.

a) Find your expected winnings for playing this game as a function of your initial bet.

Let's say the initial bet is $b$. Then are the Expected winnings going to be $1/2b+1/2s$ where $s$ the loss?

I know I am on the completely wrong track

b) Things seem a little too good to be true, so explain why playing this game wouldn't be a good idea in the long run?

Because unless you have an unlimited amount of money, and there is a limit to every table, its very likely that you can lose multiple rounds in a row and lose a lot of money in comparison to your winnings very quickly.

Comment: This is too good to be true.  No casino would let you play this game as it wins for the player on average.

Comment: This sounds like this paradox https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox.

Comment: ohh thank you. so then the expected value would just be $1/2*b+1/2*(2b)+...+1/2(nb)$?

Comment: After $n$ rounds, if you are still playing you will have lost every time with combined probability $\frac{1}{2^n}$ and lost a total amount $(2^n-1)b$ presuming you can afford this, or otherwise will stop having once won net $b$ with combined probability $1-\frac{1}{2^n}$ so an expected gain of $-\frac{1}{2^n}(2^n-1)b+(1-\frac{1}{2^n})b =0$.

Comment: When you say you win twice your bet, is that your profit so you now have three times your bet?  It should be, but the answer posted assumes otherwise.

Comment: @RossMillikan Read their example carefully. They bet \$4 and lose, then bet \$8 and win, and now they have a \$4 profit. That is consistent with my interpretation, and inconsistent with yours.

Answer (score 0):

For question $1$, your expected winnings on each bet is zero. If you bet $b$, there is a $50\%$ that you lose your bet of $b$, and a $50\%$ chance that you make a profit of $2b-b=b$. We calculate
$$
\text{expected winnings}=0.5\cdot (-b)+0.5\cdot (+b)=0.
$$
You can also talk about your expected winnings for each "phase" of this strategy, where a "phase" only ends when you finally win, doubling your bet after each loss. If the phase lasts for $n$ rounds, meaning you lose $n-1$ times and win on the $n^\text{th}$ round, then your winnings for that phase are
$$
-b-2b-4b-\cdots -b2^{n-1}+b2^n=b
$$
Since you gain $b$ no matter what, the expected gain per phase is $+b$. So the expected gain per bet is $0$, but the expected gain per phase is $+b$. This leads to the question: do you break even on average, or win on average? We have two different answers, so this is a bit of a paradox.

For question $2$, you have the right idea. My only criticism of your answer is that you say "there is a limit to every table," but this is not applicable here, because the problem specifically states "the casino does not limit your bets". The real problem is that your bets are limit by your available bankroll. If you assume that you have unlimited bankroll, then this strategy *would* win money over time. However, an unlimited bankroll cannot exist in reality; instead, the player will have finite amount of money $M$ to put at stake. If you are ever required to bet more than $M$, then you will be unable to recoup your losses for that phase, and lose a huge amount of money. Therefore, this betting system works like a reverse lottery, where most of the time you win a small amount of money, but with a small probability you lose almost all of your wealth.

This resolves the paradox from earlier; the only way to ensure you win a positive amount each phase is to start with an infinite amount of money, which is impossible in real life. Therefore, the expected gain per phase is actually $0$ in any real-world context, when you factor in the small chance of losing big. Therefore, this game really is balanced.